# Disable a btn on IE [Duplicated]

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a problem to disable an `<input>` element with JavaScript/jQuery on Internet explorer.

I tried

```
$('input[name="chooseNeedsubmit"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

and

```
$('input[name="chooseNeedsubmit"]').disable(true);
```

this is the html code of the btn:

```
<input class="action-form" type="submit" name="chooseNeedsubmit" value="Envoyer votre demande">
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you show the html with the button?

Comment: you have to add HTML also jQuery full code that you calling this `.prop`

Comment: Where are you calling the jQuery? if it is on start up are you putting into $(document).ready()?

Comment: seems your script is loading before the element is loaded . try  inserting your jquery code inside $( document ).ready(function() {// your jquery
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disableling btn in IE is not supported**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your script is loading before the element has loaded in the `DOM`.
Try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="chooseNeedsubmit"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

or Put your `<script>` tag after the `</body>` tag